# Github not logging me in on PuTTy on Windows

Tags: git, github, version-control

When I try to log into GitHub using PuTTy on Windows, I get this error

```
Username for 'https://github.com': hamood765
Password for 'https://hamood765@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hamood765/Testrepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have tried replacing my password with a personal access token yet nothing works.
Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a ssh key to your account.

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Then, set the new origin in your repo.

```sh
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/<username>/<repo>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of origin